# ¿How to make table headers laterally with css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I have a table to record service orders,in the desktop view everything is fine, but I want to make sure that when I put half the screen on the PC this one fits.

For this I want to place the headers laterally

How could I achieve this with CSS?

Or is it better for me to make a second table and hide the first one when I go to half screen?

**This is what my table looks like in full screen:**

[image]

**and this is what I want to achieve without creating a new one, just with css:**

[image]

```html
<div class="table tableUno">
  <table class="table table-bordered tablaModal" id="dataTable">
    <thead class="btn-primary">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Equipo recibido</th>
        <th scope="col">Número de serie</th>
        <th scope="col">Descripción de la falla</th>
        <th scope="col">Comentarios</th>
        <th scope="col" hidden="">Cantidad</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control letra" name="livesearchProduct[]" id="livesearchProduct" required=""></select>
        </td>
        <td>

          <!--Grupo numero de serie-->
          <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__numeroSerie">
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
              <input class="form-control formulario__input letra" type="text" name="numeroSerie[]" id="numeroSerie1" required="">
              <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!--Termina grupo numero de serie-->
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control descripcionOrden letra" name="descripcionOS[]" id="descripcionOS" cols="30" rows="3" required="" placeholder="Si no cuentas con descripcion para agregar, escribe 'NA' en este recuadro "></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control comentariosOrden letra" name="comentariosOS[]" id="comentariosOS" cols="30" rows="3" required="" placeholder="Si no cuentas con comentarios para agregar, escribe 'NA' en este recuadro "></textarea>

        </td>
        <td hidden=""><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="text" id="btnNuevoAlineamiento" value="¿Agregar registro?">
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="text" id="btnDeleteAlineamiento" value="Eliminar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do these kinds of things, I usually find it is just easier to include both the headers in the column and the rows, and show/hide them with CSS. This also lets you better control the `scope` attribute appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use tables for displaying data. For layout, use flexbox or grid. In this case, you want a grid.

Note that I have followed the principle of mobile-first design, so the markup and styles are arranged for the mobile view, then there is a @media rule to override some styles for wider screens.

After running this snippet, please use the **full page** link to test the responsive behaviour.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: auto;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
}

.header {
  background: silver;
  color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .d1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <span class="header">Equipo recibido</span>
  <span><select id="livesearchProduct"></select></span>
  <span class="header">Número de serie</span>
  <span><input type="text" id="numeroSerie1"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
  <span class="header">Descripción de la falla</span>
  <span><textarea id="descripcionOS" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Si no cuentas con descripcion para agregar, escribe 'NA' en este recuadro "></textarea></span>
  <span class="header">Comentarios</span>
  <span><textarea id="comentariosOS" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Si no cuentas con comentarios para agregar, escribe 'NA' en este recuadro "></textarea></span>
</div>
```

After running this snippet, please use the **full page** link to test the responsive behaviour.